# I need to get the name of transaction and get the name of the request, iteration, Users which is passing using selenium webdriver sampler in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to get the names of request and transaction in the results. I have to print the transaction name and request name in my code using selenium webdriver sampler. Could you please provide me some code how to get the name of request and transaction and iteration count using selenium webdriver sampler...

Expected results:
Get name of the request
Get the name of the transaction
Get the iteration count
Get the user number which is passed

Answer (score 0):

For the request name and iteration you can use the following code snippet:

```
WDS.log.info('Request name: ' + WDS.ctx.getCurrentSampler().getName())
WDS.log.info('Current iteration: ' + WDS.vars.getIteration())
```

Where:

- `WDS.log` stands for [Log4JLogger](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.html)
- `WDS.ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
- `WDS.vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Unfortunately I don't know what do you mean by "transaction" hence I'm not able to help with that.

Comment: Thank you.Could you please tell me how to get user count..